# Generate current date in stubbed's json file

Tags: wiremock

To stub http response I use WireMock.

So here my stubbed response as json file. 
Location:  `/wiremock/__files/myproject/stub.resp.json`

Content of `stub.resp.json`

```
{
  "requestId": "903004f5-7033-4aa8-a605-a10d4ff19241",
  "Code": 0,
  "Text": "Success",
  "data": {
    "request_id": "a12c6161-463b-e911-85dc-c81f66ca042a",
    "paid_currency_code": "USD",
    "transfer_amount": 1.0,
    "transfer_currency_code": "USD",
    "paid_amount": 1.0,
    "exchange_rate": 1.0,
    "referenceNumber": "123456",
    "receiverName": "Bruce Lee",
    "receiveDate": "2019-02-28T12:48:00"
  }
}
```

Nice. It's work fine.

But I have one question. As you can see the field **receiveDate** is hardcoded date-time (always `2019-02-28T12:48:00`). But I need every time when return this stub response, in the field  **receiveDate** to generate current date.

How I can do this?
And I need to generate current date in format "`yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`"

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to put something like this into your JSON response body:

`"receiveDate": "{{now format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ'}}"`

For referecence: http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/, specifically the section under the heading: "Date and time helpers".

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
"receiveDate": "{{now format='yyyy-MM-dd'}}T{{now format='HH:mm:ssZ'}}"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the current date in ISO 8601 format just use `{{ now }}`.

If you want a local time, add the timezone as a specifier, e.g.

```
{{ now timezone='Europe/London' }}
```